# Passing variable from html form to js to php

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I need an help to pass:

```
<input type="file" id="upload"/>
```

to a script in js that pass it to a php page.
In the php page i need to have this code to upload the file, but i can't retrive the variables:

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']["tmp_name"],$_FILES['uploadfile']["name"]);
```

In js script I use Ajax JQuery function to give, with POST method, the value of the html objects.

JS Code:

```
uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');

dati1="allegato="+uploader;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ineriscinew.php',
    data: dati1,
    success: function(msg){ alert(msg); }
});
```

But adopting this code i can't retrive the php variable: **$_FILES['uploadfile']["name"]**

I hope you can help me.
Thanks.

Comment: What is document.getElementById('uploader') referring to in your html?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to handle file uploading through AJAX.

Doing so (purely using JS) is possible through the new XMLHttpRequest 2 [FormData object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects).  Keep in mind though that it will only work on newer browsers (you can check compatibility [here](http://caniuse.com/xhr2)).

A more-detailed example can be found [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/) where the tutorial also shows an example of the backend code (in PHP) needed to handle the form upload.